# What is the difference between the release, share and submitubuntu commands in Quickly?

Tags: ppa, application-development, quickly

There are 3 different commands in Quickly to release a new version of an app into a PPA

- `release` - Posts a release of your project to a PPA on launchpad so that users can install the application on their system.
- `share` - Updates your PPA with the the latest saved project changes.
- `submitubuntu` - Posts a release of your project and submit it the ubuntu
  application review board so that any users can see and install the
  application ont their system.

Even after reading the help, I cannot figure out when or if I should use each one of them.

So what are the main differences between these commands and when should I use each one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those three commands are intended as three levels of "officialness" to your release.

### share

`share` does 2 main things:

1. Packages your software with a version suffix like -public1
2. Uploads that package to a PPA

So it's good for quickly getting code to testers.  Ideally you'd use a separate PPA from your normal releases.

### release

`release` does the same thing as `share` except:

1. Updates your version with a real version number like 12.04 (or whatever number you provide)
2. Saves your changes to bzr and tags it with the version number
3. Pushes a tarball of your release to your Launchpad project page

So it's good for releasing a version of your software that is ready for prime time.

### submitubuntu

`submitubuntu` does the same thing as `release` except:

1. The PPA package of your software will be setup to make it easier for the App Review Board to accept (installs your software in /opt, adds certain metadata flags, etc)

So this is good for releasing a version of your software that you also intend to submit to the ARB.  Note that this does not automatically submit it.  It just makes packaging changes to make the ARB process quicker once you do.  You will then need to point the ARB to the PPA into which you uploaded.

If you just want to test those packaging changes (like /opt), but without actually releasing, use `quickly package --extras`.

Comment: Excellent, that makes it really clear, thanks Mike!

Answer (score 7):

- `share` - This command lets you share your current developmental snapshot of your product. You should be using this command if you have added minor features or fixed bugs in your application.
- `release` - This command allows you to create a new release of your application. You should be using this command if you have added major features to indicate that it has undergone some significant improvements.
- `submitubuntu` - It is as obvious as the name can be. It allows you to `release` the project that you are working on as well as submit it to the Ubuntu application board for reviewing. If you are looking to get your application into the software-center, this command should make things a zillion times easier, as it prepares the package to install in the `/opt` directory, as required by the Ubuntu App Review Board.