# How do I push my app to Launchpad if I have followed the recommendations of the App Review Board for Quickly apps?

Tags: installation, application-development, ppa, quickly

I developed an app called [Discvur](https://launchpad.net/~agmenor/+archive/discvur) with Quickly. I intend to submit it to the App Review Board so that it can be published in the Software Center. Therefore I followed all the recommendations on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard/Submissions/QuicklyTips and changed my files accordingly.

Nevertheless, when I do `quickly share`, Quickly overwrites all my debian files. So my app is not installed in `/opt/` and I cannot launch it at all.

Am I having a bug, did I do something wrong while following the instructions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [Ubuntu App Showdown page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/):

> Run the following command to package and upload your app:
>
> `quickly submitubuntu`

You should use the `submitubuntu` command instead of `share`. `submitubuntu` will take care of everything for you, so that you don't have to modify any debian files. You may want to learn more about the difference between these commands and what other Quickly packaging commands do, so have a look at the [description of Quickly packaging commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138422/what-is-the-difference-between-the-release-share-and-submitubuntu-commands-in-q/).

Also, bear in mind that during the contest we detected some bugs in the `submitubuntu` command, so be sure to install the version of Quickly that fixes the most critical one, as described in the [App Developer Blog announcement](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/07/ubuntu-app-showdown-deadline-approaching-get-your-submissions-ready/).

Answer (score 1):

According to the source package you did not apply the changes to `debian/rules`.

Comment: It looks like `quickly share` overwrites my manual changes…

Comment: I just modified all the debian files again and reuploaded my app. I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about Quickly. Try to create your package using `quickly package --extras` and then use `dput ppa:agmenor/discvur  ../discvur_0.1-public21_source.changes` to upload it.

Comment: When I do `quickly package --extras`, I obtain a file called `../discvur_0.1-0extras12.04.1_amd64.changes`, not `source.changes`.